# Prevent user from entering uppercase-only values in text fields

Tags: html, validation

I have a booking system where the customer's name has to be entered into a simple html5 input field (type text). Some bookers continuously enter the name in uppercase characters. Is there a way (via Javascript probably) to change the case to normal title case (first character and characters after a space uppercase, following characters lower case)? But wait, it's not *that* easy...

Complication: If there would be no McArthurs or MacDonalds in this world I would solve this via regexp in the pattern attribute of the input field and then a use a script to transform the content on cursor leaving the field. We do not know at this point, if there are other naming parts like Mc or Mac (international customers). I would assume these types of "name addons" are at least 2 characters long - don't remember seeing a single character one.

How would you approach this issue?

Edit: solved by the answer of [deceze](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59213736/prevent-user-from-entering-uppercase-only-values-in-text-fields#comment104643780_59213736).

Comment: https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/

Comment: @Oen44 I want "MACARTHUR" shown as "MacArthur". `toLowerCase` would result in "macarthur".

Comment: If you don't know what changes need to be made, how will you know if any code to make them is correct?

Comment: @ScottHunter well I was thinking about a regexp in the form "Uppercase character followed by 1 or more lower case characters followed by another uppercase character or a space" which repeats null or more times over the name. But after reading deceze's link I just think about ignoring the uppercase issue.

Comment: John H.A.L. de Jong says: that's probably a good idea. ☝️

Answer (score 0):

I would create an array of common starts of last names:

```
let common = ["mac", "mc"]; // add more obv.
```

Then, check the last name:

```
let lastName = "macarthur"; // this would be input that would have been called with .toLowerCase
let isSplit = false
for (let x in lastName) {
    if (lastName.startsWith(x)) {
        isSplit = true;
    }
}

// if isSplit is now true, you can capitalize accordingly
```

Comment: Good luck covering *all possible cases* with this…

Comment: Honestly there is no "all covering" solution that I can think of. This would work for most common lastnames